# Pasting merge cells to new sheet are pasting unmerged

Tags: vba, excel

My current macro copies data from one page(A) and pastes in another(B).

In page A I have merged cells, when it pastes in B these cells are not merged.

Is there any code I can add to this to make sure the merged cells are not unmerged?

This is what I tried,

```
  Case paste_cx Like "*Merged Cells*" Or select_cx Like "*Print Area*" Or select_cx Like "*Box*"
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Range(to_col_start & to_lin_start & ":" & to_col_end & to_lin_end).Copy
        Range(to_col_start & to_lin_start & ":" & to_col_end & to_lin_end).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Posting newly tried code:

```
     Case paste_cx Like "*Merged Cells*" Or select_cx Like "*Print Area*" Or select_cx Like "*Box*"
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Range(to_col_start & to_lin_start & ":" & to_col_end & to_lin_end).Copy
        ''Range(to_col_start & to_lin_start & ":" & to_col_end & to_lin_end).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        With Range(to_col_start & to_lin_start & ":" & to_col_end & to_lin_end)   ''newly tested, doesnt work.
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        End With


        'if the last row is merged
        If Range(to_col_start & to_lin_end).End(xlUp).MergeCells And Len(Range(to_col_start & to_lin_end).End(xlUp).Value) > 20 Then
            Set rng = Range(to_col_start & to_lin_end).End(xlUp).MergeArea
        ElseIf Range(to_col_start & to_lin_end).MergeCells And Len(Range(to_col_start & to_lin_end).Value) > 20 Then
            Set rng = Range(to_col_start & to_lin_end).MergeArea
        End If
```

Comment: You're doing `.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues` so that's expected. You need to paste the formatting also.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the macro recorder and try to get what you need, you will see that `xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme` is the `PasteSpecial` type, which keeps the merge cells. Thus, add this line additionally. It will keep the merge:

```
With Range(to_col_start & to_lin_start & ":" & to_col_end & to_lin_end)
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
End With
```

If you want to keep both values and formats, use `xlPasteValues` and `xlPasteFormats` after each other:

```
With Range(to_col_start & to_lin_start & ":" & to_col_end & to_lin_end)
   .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
   .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
End With
```

[MSDN for XlPasteType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlpastetype-enumeration-excel)

---

Here is some minimal working example, of a code that copies range from the first worksheet and pastes it to the second. It takes care to copy the values and pastes the merged cells exactly as they are:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim mySourceRng As Range
    Dim myTargetRng As Range

    Set mySourceRng = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:F10")
    Set myTargetRng = Worksheets(2).Range("A1:F10")
    mySourceRng.Copy

    With myTargetRng
       .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
       .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False        
End Sub
```

Comment: should I replace my paste line with this with statement above? I've tried doesnt seem to work

Comment: @excelguy - try with the second statement, which is 4 lines. But do not forget the `.Copy` from your code before.

Comment: thanks for your help, doesnt seem to work sigh, i posted more of my code. I'll keep trying to play with this

Comment: @excelguy - try the minimal code in the edit. You will get the idea and you will be able to fix it within your code.